# C++ macro that removes quotes from input

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm in search of solution of one strange problem referred to c++ define macros. So, I want to write a define macro which would take one string parameter

```
MACRO("str"); //usage of macro
```

and expand in code to

```
str // without qoutes!
```

How should the macros appear?

Comment: Nope, you can't turn the type of a token into another type, with the special case of stringification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to define such a macro.

You can stringize a token or sequence of tokens, but you cannot "unstringize" a string literal.

Comment: Ok, thank you for answer anyway. I would be very thankful if c++ standardization working group included this feature in next cpp specification, but they might never include it..

Comment: @user1824491 What is your objective? Perhaps someone can suggest an alternative solution for you.